# Collator plus Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, localization

I have a collection of beans OptionItemDTO (properties label and value) and I'm currently using something like this to sort by label:

```
Collections.sort(combo, new LabelComparator())
```

The problem is that it does not sort stressed vowels (my locale is spanish).

According to this document http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/sorting_strings I must use a Collator class.

But if I use the sort with collator, I can't use the comparator (and vice-versa). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From Java Doc: 
Collator implements Comparator so it is already a comparator.
Can you show us the code where it does not work?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your LabelComparator should delegate to a Collator to compare the labels of your DTOs:

```
public int compare(OptionItemDTO dto1, OptionItemDTO dto2) {
    return collator.compare(dto1.getLabel(), dto2.getLabel());
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, merci beaucoup

Comment: Note however that the JavaDoc of Collator recommends to use CollationKeys for sorting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Comment: Warning: you should create the collator with the proper locale.

Comment: @Puce: that is only worth the price only of the list to sort is very long. And in this case LabelComparator makes me believe we are talking UI, so I would not expect tens of thousands of entries (if that is the case, then it is probably pretty bad UI design :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small framework to sort collections of objects with CollationKeys (rather than Collators):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/text/Localizables.html

You just have to implement a Localizer (or make your POJO implement Localizable) to provide a string representation:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/text/Localizer.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/text/Localizable.html

You can have a look at the unit tests for some samples:

http://softsmithy.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/softsmithy/lib/main-golden/file/5c4db802573b/lib-core/src/test/java/org/softsmithy/lib/text/LocalizablesTest.java

The library is open source.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.1/

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```